# Change variable by reference in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a value, i want to pass it to a function and change the original value from withinf the fuction and show it on the screen... im using react hooks. i dont want to use the state/setState, because the value is like 10 layers deep into a json, so it would be very hard to change it using spread... heres an example of what i want to do:

```
let data = {
 phase:{
   document:{
     name: 'Example'}
   }
} 

changeName(phase.document.name)

function changeName(name){
 name = "Changed name"
}
```

after that i want to display the changed name... is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set):

```
let data = {
  phase: {
    document: {
      name: "Example",
    },
  },
};

const shallowCopy = { ...data };
lodash.set(shallowCopy, `phase.document.name`, `New Changed Name`);

// You must change the reference in order to render
setState(shallowCopy);
```